# can not understand in gcd algorithm

Tags: python

Help us understand one point in this algorithm.

Why for `b > a` in the first pass `a` and `b` swap places: `(800,225)`?

Why does the operation `a%b` fail?

```py
def gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b, a % b)

print(gcd(225, 800))
```

Comment: Look up what `a % b` does. Think about what the result of that operation would be when b > a. What happens when you send that as the second argument to the recursion

Comment: Why do you say `a%b` fails? When `0 <= a < b` then `a%b==a`. That is a property of modulo arithmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise you so simply try it out: the whole idea of the gcd algorithm is to replace the largest number by the smallest, and the smallest by the modulo, as in your example:

GCD (225,800):

The smallest is 225
The modulo is '800-3*225', which equals 125.

So: GCD (225, 800) = GCD (125, 225)

From now on you're started and you can continue till the end (the modulo being zero).

If you don't check which one is the largest and which one the smallest number, you'll end up with:

GCD (225, 800):

The modulo is 225, because 225 = 0*800 + 225, so:

GCD (225, 800) = GCD (225, 800)

You're stuck!

Answer (score 1):

If b is greater than a, then `a % b` is simply a, because `a % b` is the integer division remainder (modulo), and a / b is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers the question, but if you are asking why the values swap places, you need to understand the Euclidean algorithm.

### Why do we swap?

Here is a way that I was explained:

Imagine you have two numbers `a` and `b`, and you want to find the GCD. By definition, the GCD is the largest number that both `a` and `b` divide without a remainder. Now, let's see how this could be reasoned:

We can write the relationship between a and b as

```
a = b * c0 + r0
```

In the example above the `c0` and `r0` are some whole numbers, with `r0` being a remainder (that is `r0 = a % b`).

We can also rewrite the `b` and the `r0` in a similar fashion:

```
b = r0 * c1 + r1
```

Notice that the `b` took the place of `a` and the `r0` took the place of the `b`. This is exactly the swap step. You repeat this process until `rX` becomes 0 (that is no remainder exists).

### Are assumptions right?

The correctness of the Euclidean comes from the assumption that

```
GCD(a, b) = GCD(b, r)
```

where `a = b * c + r`. And here is the proof:

1. Let `k` be ANY common divisor of `a` and `b` (not necessarily greatest). In that case, `a = c1 * k` and `b = c2 * k`, where `c1` and `c2` are whole numbers
2. In such a case `k` is also a common divisor for `b` and `r`, because `b` divides by `k` as defined in (1) and `r = a - b * c = (c1 - c2 * c) * k` (it's just rearranging the (1), (2), and the original statement).
3. The opposite of (2) is also true (proof is similar to (2)): any common divisor of `b` and `r` is also a common divisor for `a` and `b`
4. That means that all common divisors of tuples `(a, b)` and `(b, r)` overlap. In other words, tuple `(a, b)` has no common divisor that is not a common divisor of `(b, r)`, and vice versa.
5. In particular, the GREATEST common divisor has to be the same for both tuples, because if you assume `GCD(a, b) > GCD(b, r)` or `GCD(a, b) < GCD(b, r)` will cause contradictions in one of the previous statements. Hence, `GCD(a, b)` has to be equal to `GCD(b, r)` => `GCD(a, b) = GCD(b, a % b)`